# Printing the objects contained in the keys on separate lines

Tags: python

I am trying to print the objects contained in the keys in the alphabetical order of the keys and on separate lines. Up to now, I was able to print the objects on separate lines. However, when I introduced  `y=sort(x)` the program malfunctions. Thanks for the help.

JSON file (trying to print the right part on separate lines without the u)

```
{

    "title" : "The story of the very very very hungry caterpillar",

    "author" : "Erik Karle",

    "publisher" : "Penguine Putnam",

    "genre" : "children's literature",

    "summary": "this book is a total knockoff of the excellent book _The Very Hungry Caterpillar_ written by Eric Carle"
}
```

My code:

```
import json

def read_json(filename):

    dt = {}

    fh = open(filename, "r")
    dt = json.load(fh)

    return dt


def print_values_order_by_keys(dt):

    sorted_keys = sorted(dt)
    objects = sorted_keys()
    for object in objects:
        print object
    ###for key in sorted_keys:
        ###print key

filename = raw_input("Enter the JSON file: ")
r = read_json(filename)
print_values_order_by_keys(r)
```

Comment: "objects"? Do you mean the *values* of the corresponding keys? You can get a list of values using `dt.values()`

Comment: would that get the values of all the keys or for only a specific one?

Comment: ... it returns a list of *all the values*. You seem to understand that you get the value of a key by using `dt[some_key]`... I don't understand what you don't understand... you seem to have all the necessary information. Try changing your `print` statement to `print object, dt[object]` ... perhaps that will be illuminating.

Comment: I wrote down the code as you told. It indeed gave me the list of all the values contained in the keys. However, is it possible to print each values on separate lines and without the unicode preceding it

Comment: Have you tried `print_values (r \n) ` to force a new line? The flow through the functions seems odd as well but my wine input just hit the buffer so I can't parse very well at the moment

Comment: so basically print objects (r \n) instead of only print objects?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import json

def read_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        return json.load(fh)

def print_values(obj):
    for name, value in sorted(obj.items()):
        print('{}: {}'.format(name, value))

filename = raw_input('Enter the JSON file: ')
r = read_json(filename)
print_values(r)
```

Output:

```
author: Erik Karle
genre: children's literature
publisher: Penguine Putnam
summary: this book is a total knockoff of the excellent book _The Very Hungry Caterpillar_ written by Eric Carle
title: The story of the very very very hungry caterpillar
```

Comment: "title" : "The story of the very very very hungry caterpillar",
"author" : "Erik Karle",
"publisher" : "Penguine Putnam",
"genre" : "children's literature",
"summary": "this book is a total knockoff of the excellent book                    I'm trying to print the right part on separate lines without the U

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the information to it. It's also very important to include the very beginning of the file and possibly the last few lines, too. When you say something is causing an error, please also indicate on what line it occurred.

Comment: Done. Hope with the information give you can direct me in the good path

Comment: That doesn't look like a properly formatted json file, so `json.load()` won't work with it. Try just copying and pasting a few lines from the beginning of file into your question.

Comment: I was able to answer my previous. So I modified a bit my initial question using sort

Comment: Thanks for editing. I'm new and still a beginner in learning how to properly use this website. Any suggestion for my question?

Comment: You're welcome. In the future I would suggest adding sample input whenever possible to enable others to recreate the problem and see if they have fixed it. Another very important aspect of asking question, is learning how use Stackoverflow's "markdown" syntax to properly format any code and data you have in your question.

Comment: For my particular problem, obj = dt, items = values?

Comment: `obj` is a Python dictionary  `json.load()` returned after reading the file, it's basically what you named `dt` in your code. Python dictionaries have a method called `items()` which returns a list of all the key, value pairs the dictionary contains—so it's more than just values. You can see all the methods dictionaries have by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) on them.

Comment: P.S. Also suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow it in the future